# GetAddrInfoW to get only the global ipv6 address

Tags: visual-c++

I need only my global IPv6 address and not local link address. I have set ai_flags to AI_ADDRCONFIG as mentioned in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738519(v=vs.85).aspx). But GetAddrInfoW returns both global and local link addresses. Is there any way i can find out from `ADDRINFOW` result structure the type of address?

```
 std::wstring whostname = L"hostname";
    ADDRINFOW hints;
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(ADDRINFOW));
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;      // IPv4 and IPv6
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;  // TCP only, no UDP
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG; // Get only global IPv6 address

    ADDRINFOW *list = NULL;
    result = GetAddrInfoW(
        whostname.c_str(), 
        NULL,             
        &hints,
        &list
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there isnt something that the API provides to get only the global IPv6 address. I have managed to identify the global address based on the IPv6 address format.  From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses), The scope can be used to identify Link-local address.